# #1066 - error not unique table alias

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1066

I am learning mysql and I am having trouble with one of my tables which produces #1066 - error not unique table alias. I have tried a number of different queries but all have the same result. Can someone put me out of my misery and help point out what I am doing wrong! - Thanks

Tables

```
looks
---------

look_id(Pk)
user_id
title
description
date_modified

Add_Look_Item
-----------------------

look_id (fk from table 1)
item_id (fk from table 3)

Item
--------------

item_id (pk)
name
details

Add_Images
-------------------
image_id (pk)
item_id (fk from table 3)
image_name
```

Queries I have tried - add_look_item is a compound key

```
SELECT DISTINCT looks.look_id, looks.title, looks.date_modified, add_look_item.item_id,     add_images.image_name FROM looks JOIN add_look_item ON add_look_item.look_id = looks.look_id
JOIN add_look_item ON add_look_item.item_id = item.item_id WHERE look.user_id = 94

#1066 - error not unique table alias 'add_look_item

SELECT DISTINCT looks.look_id, looks.title, looks.date_modified, add_look_item.item_id,     add_images.image_name FROM looks JOIN 
add_look_item ON add_look_item.looks_id = look.look_id
JOIN add_look_item ON add_look_item.item_id = item.item_id
JOIN add_images ON add_images.item_id = item.item_id WHERE add_look_item.item_id =    item.item_id AND look.user_id = 94

#1066 - error not unique table alias 'add_look_item

SELECT DISTINCT looks.look_id, looks.title, looks.date_modified, add_look_item.item_id,   add_images.image_name FROM looks INNER JOIN add_look_item ON add_look_item.look_id =    look_look_id
INNER JOIN add_images ON add_images.item_id = item.item_id
INNER JOIN add_look_item ON add_look_item.item_id = item.item_id
WHERE look.user_id = 94

#1066 - error not unique table alias 'add_look_item

SELECT DISTINCT looks.look_id, looks.title, looks.date_modified, add_look_item.item_id,    add_images.image_name FROM looks 
INNER JOIN add_look_item ON add_look_item.looks_id = look.look_id
INNER JOIN add_images ON add_images.item_id = item.item_id
INNER JOIN add_look_item ON add_look_item.item_id = item.item_id 
WHERE add_look_item.item_id = item.item_id AND look.user_id = 94


#1066 - error not unique table alias 'add_look_item

SELECT DISTINCT looks.look_id, looks.title, looks.date_modified, add_look_item.item_id,    add_images.image_name FROM looks 
INNER JOIN add_look_item ON add_look_item.looks_id = look.look_id
INNER JOIN add_images ON add_images.item_id = item.item_id
WHERE add_look_item.item_id = item.item_id AND look.user_id = 94

#1054 - Unknown column 'item.item_id' in 'where clause'
```

Thanks

Comment: I need these values looks.look_id, looks.title, looks.date_modified, add_look_item.item_id,     add_images.image_name, thanks

Comment: Why are joining the same table multiple times if you just want that?

Comment: the way I am understanding it is that I am accessing values across 4 tables so I would need to join these? or is there a much easier and better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
SELECT looks.look_id, looks.title, looks.date_modified, add_look_item.item_id, add_images.image_name
FROM looks
JOIN add_look_item
    ON looks.look_id = add_look_item.look_id
JOIN add_images
    ON add_look_item.item_id = add_images.item_id
WHERE look.user_id = 94
```

Comment: Thanks nnichols but returns #1054 - Unknown column 'ali1.item_id' in 'on clause'must be because ali1 has not been set?

Answer (score 1):

Make an alias for add_look_item since you are joining it multiple times.

For example:

```
SELECT tbl.a, a.y, b.y 
FROM tbl 
JOIN tbl2 as a ON tbl.x = a.x 
JOIN tbl2 as b ON tbl.x = b.x
```

Otherwise the query engine won't know what to do :)