# Another MySQL 1066. Not unique table/alias: 'events' when selecting from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I've read through several SO posts regarding this problem and I'm still not understanding the solution.  I think I'm just missing some little thing that'll make this work properly:

[**#1066 - Not unique table/alias:**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590007/1066-not-unique-table-alias)

[**#1066 - error not unique table alias**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041954/1066-error-not-unique-table-alias)

[**#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'tb_X'**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381150/1066-not-unique-table-alias-tb-x)

Here's one variant on the queries I've tried, if I run this, MySQL Workbench 6.1 just goes off into la-la-land and I have to cancel the query.

```
SELECT `events`.`DateTime`, `events`.`User`, `eventdetails`.`ItemName`, `eventdetails`.`ItemValue`
FROM `events`, `eventdetails`
INNER JOIN `events` events1 ON `events1`.`Event_ID` = `eventDetails`.`Event_ID` 
WHERE `events`.`PCBID` = 12946
ORDER BY `events`.`DateTime` DESC;
```

This variant gives me the 1066 error in the title:

```
SELECT `events`.`DateTime`, `events`.`User`, `eventdetails`.`ItemName`, `eventdetails`.`ItemValue`
FROM`events`,   `eventdetails`
INNER JOIN `events` ON `events`.`Event_ID` = `eventDetails`.`Event_ID` 
WHERE `events`.`PCBID` = 12946
ORDER BY `events`.`DateTime` DESC;
```

I understand that I'm using the `events` table twice, but don't seem to be able to get a workable version that doesn't time out.

**My Data:**

The 'events' result should come from these rows:

```
Event_ID    | PCBID | EventType_ID  | DateTime              | User
73819       | 12946 | 1             | 03-Sep-09 07:10:07    | USERNAME
73992       | 12946 | 1             | 11-Sep-09 06:51:09    | USERNAME
74159       | 12946 | 1             | 16-Sep-09 07:22:49    | USERNAME
74445       | 12946 | 1             | 08-Jan-10 13:41:16    | USERNAME
```

And the 'eventdetails' result should come from these rows:

```
EventDetails_ID | Event_ID  | ItemName          | ItemValue
37595           | 73819     | SBESerialNumber   | 70000862 
37948           | 73992     | Notes             | Passed IMM Cold Test B 
38115           | 74159     | Notes             | passed UCSD specific timing test 
38423           | 74445     | SBESerialNumber   | 00000000
```

**Desired Results:**

The results I'm looking for should look something like this:

```
DateTime            | User      | ItemName          | ItemValue
03-Sep-09 07:10:07  | USERNAME  | SBESerialNumber   | 70000862 
11-Sep-09 06:51:09  | USERNAME  | Notes             | Passed IMM Cold Test B 
16-Sep-09 07:22:49  | USERNAME  | Notes             | passed UCSD specific timing test 
08-Jan-10 13:41:16  | USERNAME  | SBESerialNumber   | 00000000
```

Comment: The first query works for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bdd6/1

Comment: Why are you joining with `events` twice? You're never using anything from `events1`.

Comment: @Barmar i believe that the OP is trying to remove the Cartesian Product with that join... instead of just doing it the right way

Comment: @JohnRuddell What is "the right way"?  I'm still learning MySQL (had to look up Cartesian Product), so I'm interested to know if there's a better way to do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to join with `events` twice.

```
SELECT `events`.`DateTime`, `events`.`User`, `eventdetails`.`ItemName`, `eventdetails`.`ItemValue`
FROM `eventdetails`
INNER JOIN `events` ON `events`.`Event_ID` = `eventDetails`.`Event_ID` 
WHERE `events`.`PCBID` = 12946
ORDER BY `events`.`DateTime` DESC;
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bdd6/3)

Comment: Your solution works perfectly, and now I understand what I was doing wrong (or at least I think I do).  Thanks for the help and the example on sqlfiddle.

Comment: @delliottg barmars answer details what I was saying. you should not do `FROM eventdetails, events`... you should have a root table and JOIN the other tables together.